# How to accomplish scoped variable reset in C#?

Tags: c#

One common pattern I see and use frequently in C++ is to temporarily set a variable to a new value, and then reset it when I exit that scope.  In C++, this is easily accomplished with references and templated scope classes, and allows for increased safety and prevention of errors where the variable is set to a new value, then reset to an incorrect assumed initial value.

Here is a simplified example of what I mean (in C++):

```
void DoSomething()
{
    // The following line captures GBL.counter by reference, stores its current
    // value, and sets it to 1
    ScopedReset<int> resetter(GBL.counter, 1);

    // In this function and all below, GBL.counter will be 1
    CallSomethingThatNeedsCounterOf1();

    // When I hit the close brace, ~ScopedReset will be called, and it will
    // reset GBL.counter to it's previous value
}
```

Is there any way to do this in C#?  I've found the hard way that I can't capture a ref parameter inside an IEnumerator or a lambda, which were my first two thoughts.  I don't want to use the unsafe keyword if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first challenge to doing this in C# is dealing with non-deterministic destruction. Since C# doesn't have destructors you need a mechanism to control scope in order to execute the reset. `IDisposable` helps there and the `using` statement will mimic C++ deterministic destruction semantics.

The second is getting at the value you want to reset without using pointers. Lambdas and delegates can do that.

```
class Program
{
    class ScopedReset<T> : IDisposable
    {
        T originalValue = default(T);
        Action<T> _setter;
        public ScopedReset(Func<T> getter, Action<T> setter, T v)
        {
            originalValue = getter();
            setter(v);
            _setter = setter;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _setter(originalValue);
        }
    }

    static int counter = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        counter++;
        counter++;

        Console.WriteLine(counter); 
        using (new ScopedReset<int>(() => counter, i => counter = i, 1))            
            Console.WriteLine(counter);

        Console.WriteLine(counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Indeed, RAII in C# is entirely dependent on `IDisposable` and `using`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  This was the solution I came up with as well.  I was just hoping there was something a bit cleaner or with less overhead, perhaps.  My version skipped the getter lambda and just directly passed in counter by value, since that lambda doesn't accomplish anything useful here.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply copy the reference value to a new local variable, and use this new variable throughout your method, i.e. copy value by value?

Indeed, changing it from a `ref` to regular value parameter will accomplish this!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can capture a ref paramenter to a local variable, and have it stay a ref - a local copy will be created.

GBL.counter is effectively an implicit, hidden parameter to CallSomethingThatNeedsCounterOf1. If you could convert it to a regular, declared paraemter your problem would go away. Also, if that would result in to many parameters, a solution would be a pair of methods which set up and reset the environment so that CallSomethingThatNeedsCounterOf1() can run.

You can create a class that calls the SetUp method in its constructor and the Reset method in Dispose(). You can use this class with the using statement, to aproximate the c++ behaviour. You would, however, have to create one of these classes for each scenario.